# Mutating vector's element in place using async Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, concurrency, future, rust-tokio

Let's say I have a basic struct:

```
pub struct Course {
    pub id : i32
}
```

I want to modify this struct's inner elements. Let's say earlier I have read from a database and read Course's into a vector.

How can I achieve this? I have a lot of vector's in this type, for example Departments, Buildings, Sections etc... I'm also doing a lot of IO bound operations with them. For example inserting to database, or reading from file or mutating bunch of them while doing operations on them.

Up to this point in my project I have never used Arc or Mutex or anything future related. Yes almost all my functions are async await but they are blocking and not spawned. (I realize that this is a mistake to not think about async at the start of my project but I'm new to Rust)

Minimally what I'm trying to do:

```
pub async fn async_test(courses: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Course>>>) {
    let mut handles = vec![];

    let mut courses = courses.clone().lock().await.clone();
    for course in courses.iter_mut() {
        let handle = task::spawn(async move {
            println!("SPAWNED TASK FOR COURSE: {}", course.id);
            do_something(course);
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }
    join_all(handles).await;
}

pub async fn do_something(course: &mut Course) {
    course.id = 12345;
    for i in 1..10 {
        println!("{}", i);
        tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
error[E0597]: `courses` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:31:19
   |
30 |     let mut courses = courses.clone().lock().await.clone();
   |         ----------- binding `courses` declared here
31 |     for course in courses.iter_mut() {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                   |
   |                   borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                   argument requires that `courses` is borrowed for `'static`
...
39 | }
   | - `courses` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I'm just missing something about Rust async futures because compiler warnings seems unhelpful and I couldn't find any help online.

Thank you!

Comment: You've stacked the types wrong, it  should be `Vec<Arc<Mutex<Course>>>` as you want to share single `Course`s not the vector of them.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't easily solveable the way you have it written right now.

`tokio::task::spawn` has to be `'static`, meaning it cannot depend on anything. Meaning, you cannot pass references into it. The reason is that it might run on a different thread, and the same ownership rules as normal Rust threads apply here.

The fact that you `join_all` at the end doesn't really mean anything - the `JoinHandle`s returned by `spawn` aren't actually attached to anything. If the `async_test` task gets cancelled, this doesn't actually cancel the spawned tasks, leaving references dangling. This is what the compiler prevents, and why it doesn't allow references out of spawned tasks.

Sadly, this is also true for `Mutex`es - having a `Mutex` around the entire `Vec` isn't enough to spawn the single elements into tasks. But even having every single element wrapped in its own `Mutex` wouldn't be enough - the central problem here is that there really is no way of passing references into tasks, making this entire problem impossible in its current layout.

With normal threads, the simple solution to this problem would be [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html). Sadly, something like this for `async` doesn't exist in the `std` library.

There are crates that achieve the same in `tokio`, like [`async_scoped`](https://docs.rs/async-scoped). This is how a solution with `async_scoped` would look like:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

use async_scoped::TokioScope;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;

pub struct Course {
    pub id: i32,
}

pub async fn async_test(courses: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Course>>>) {
    let mut courses = courses.lock().await;

    // Be aware that `scope_and_collect` is **NOT** cancellation safe.
    unsafe {
        TokioScope::scope_and_collect(|s| {
            for course in courses.iter_mut() {
                s.spawn(async move {
                    println!("SPAWNED TASK FOR COURSE: {}", course.id);
                    do_something(course).await;
                });
            }
        })
        .await
    };
}

pub async fn do_something(course: &mut Course) {
    course.id = 12345;
    for i in 1..10 {
        println!("{}", i);
        tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }
}
```

Be aware that there is no cancellation-safe way to implement such a scope (in general); that's why this function requires an `unsafe` around it. The reason why this works with normal threads and not with async tasks is that normal threads are not cancellable. This fact makes it impossible to write a generic scope based spawning mechanism for async tasks.

A safer way to achieve this would require an architectural rework without references; by either passing ownership into the spawned tasks, or by using many `Arc`s.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on the unsafe contract here. What does it mean that `scope_and_collect` is not cancelation-safe - that you're not supposed to cancel anything that calls it? In other words, should `async_test()` be marked unsafe with an unsafe contract saying "don't cancel this"?

Comment: Hi @Finomnis ! Thank you very much for your detailed response. I have two questions:

1) You said that normal threads are not cancellable. I guarantee that my tasks won't be cancelled too. Is it better for me to use regular threads? However my project is IO bound instead of CPU bound and I have read that for IO bound tasks async is way to go.

2) I'd really like to learn more about a better architecture that allows easier async. Can you give me little examples or can you point me to a source that I can learn about them?

Comment: @BahadırAydın For 1), I'm not sure. If your project is IO bound, then async is indeed recommended in most cases. For 2), I can't really propose a better a architecture because I would have to see more of your usecase. Some good reads are https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial and https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book; but in the end it's like other problems: trial and error until you find an architecture that works for you. And https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, where you can post existing code with the request to improve it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll dive into them. @Finomnis